# SAPUI5 add icon after column header text

Tags: sapui5

I have a custom table with several columns. Each column has a header text (e.g. name or age). By clicking the header text, the column gets sorted. I want to add a sap icon (`sort-ascending` / `sort-descending`) after the header text as soon as it is clicked.

This should symbolize how the column is sorted. I cant use the standard sort icons. How can I do that for my custom table? How to add a style class for this case maybe?

Comment: Which table your are using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Grid table](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.Sorting/preview) by default will show the sorting icon.